# How to connect a NEW Azure App Service to HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, azure, devextreme

I am new to Azure and try to connect my existing HTML5/JS DevExtreme app to the **new** Azure App Service i created. That worked fine with the "old" Azure Mobile Service and i found a lot of samples for doing that. There is even no Quick Start sample in Azure.

I added the following lines of code to my app:

index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.7.min.js"></script>
```

home.js:

```
var _client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/");
```

How can i do that using the **new** Azure App Service? I even get no error message when using the code above but data inserts in my Azure SQL database table are not working.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: There is a missing slash in the `script src` URL, before `MobileServices.Web-1.2.7.min.js`.

Comment: Thanks Pietro. That happended while pasting the code here. It's correct in my VS project.

Comment: I am trying to solve this same question. The line of code from your `index.html` file is very similar to mine (which works against an old Mobile Service app). I am guessing that SDK (MobileServices.Web) won't work against an App Service Mobile App. Like you, though, I cannot find any reference to a comparable "AppServices.Web" to link against. I am worried that it's going to be a lot more complicated with direct HTTP calls. Any updates?